# I write code to delete the data in database, but when I run, its always say execution problem

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-c++

I write code to delete the data in database, but when I run, its always say execution problem. There is the code

```
void deleteCustomer()
{
    string customerID;
    char o;
    system("cls");
    cout << " Enter Customer ID : ";
    cin >> customerID;

    system("cls");
    do
    {
        
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\tY for Yes | N for No" << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOption : ";
        cin >> o;
        if (o == 'Y' || o == 'y')
        {        
        `i think the error in this line but i dont know where the error`        
            string delete_query = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE customerID = '" + customerID + "'";
            const char* q = delete_query.c_str();
            qstate = mysql_query(conn, q); 
            if (!qstate)
            {
                cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\Order have been removed";
                _getch();
                CustomerInfo();
            }
            else
            {

        `the output appear is Query Execution Problem`
                cout << "Query Execution Problem " << mysql_errno(conn) << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CashierMenu();
        }
    } while (o != 'y' && o != 'Y' && o != 'n' && o != 'N');
}
```

the output appear is Query Execution Problem

I think the error in this line but I don't know where the error

Comment: You should learn about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You are writing code that would be create security vulnerabilities. Someone could pass SQL code through `customerID` to be executed.

Comment: Where does `conn` come from? For a [MCVE], we need something reproducible, and we have no way to know whether `conn` is valid. For that matter, there's no declaration of `qstate`, so for all we know it's declared as something weird that `int` can coerce to, which could cause the `if` check to fail. You also omitted the error from `mysql_errno` (seems like you might want to use `mysql_error` instead in any event, since the string description is likely to be more useful than the raw numeric error code).

Answer (score -1):

try this:
string delete_query = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE customerID = ";
delete_query.append(customerID);